# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'flightSearch' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, forms, jsp

A number of questions regarding this error have been asked. But I could not find a solution.
This is my form :

```
    <form:form id="flightSearchForm" modelAttribute="flightSearch" action="searchFlights"
    method="post">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="departureLocation">Departure Location: </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="departureLocation" name="departureLocation" id="departureLocation" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="arrivalLocation">Arrival Location:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="arrivalLocation" name="arrivalLocation"
                    id="arrivalLocation" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="flightDate">Flight Date</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input type="date" path="flightDate" name="flightDate"
                    id="flightDate" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="flightClass">Flight Class</form:label></td>
            <td><form:select path="flightClass" name="flightClass"
                    items = "${flightClasses}" id="flightClass" /></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="outputPreference">Output Preference</form:label></td>
            <td><form:select path="outputPreference" name="outputPreference"
                    items = "${outputPreferences}" id="outputPreference" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td align="left"><form:button id="search" name="search">Search</form:button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

This is my controller :

```
 @Controller
 public class FlightSearchController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showWelcomePage()
{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("flightSearch", new FlightSearch());
    mav.setViewName("welcome.jsp");
    return mav;
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/searchFlights" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView searchForFlights(@ModelAttribute("flightSearch") FlightSearch flightSearch)
{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("depLoc", flightSearch.getDepartureLocation());
    mav.addObject("arrivalLocation", flightSearch.getArrivalLocation());
    mav.addObject("flightDate",flightSearch.getFlightDate());
    mav.setViewName("flightDetails.jsp");
    return mav;

}
```

}

I have tried almost every solution mentioned here but could not solve the issue. I'm new to Spring, so please help if possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can someone please help? I've been stuck for quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add @SessionAttributes("flightSearch") on your controller.

The model object will be, behind the scene, bound to the session after the get, and can then be retrieved in the post.

You need to clean the session afterwards in the post method, using SessionStatus.setComplete (or something like that).

You just need to add SessionStatus to the post method parameters.

This is how you implement 'get and post' form workflow in spring mvc I think.

Comment: Its not working and I would like to add that I'm coming to the search page after being directed from a login page using ModelAndView.setViewName().

Answer (score 0):

As You have mentioned in the comment you are redirecting.

Assuming that your above jsp code is 'welcome.jsp'

It seems Like you are redirecting it to jsp page instead of RequestMapping value

Try This:

```
    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView(); 
    mv.setViewName("redirect:welcome"); //Code Should added where you redirecting the login page to search page
```